# Targets, build,schemes iOs aclarations

Tags: ios, ios-targets

I have a iOs app that should change its style and logos in function of which company ask us for the app.

What I want is, have different configurations for the same app, so I can put a folder there with the personalization, create a new configuration, and compile it(In android we use flavors, In web we use .css folder, so it is easy to make a new version).

I think that you can achieve this with Targets, schemes and build configurations but I cant figure out how this exactly work as I cant find a good example of what I want

Comment: You will be publishing different apps on app store after updating the assets?

Comment: yes, exactly, they will have different bundle identifier

Comment: In iOS you'll have to make multiple targets for this purpose. Here is a link for your reference(https://pugpig.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204412465-Adding-new-targets-to-xCode-6-projects)